# Using Xpath to Scrape lat lons

Tags: python, xpath

I wish to use xpath to scrape open address for lat/lons of addresses. I have the following simple code that returns [].

```
from lxml import html

import requests

page = requests.get('http://alpha.openaddressesuk.org/streets/frm7qQ')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
datalatlon = tree.xpath('//span[@class="html-attribute-value"]/text()')    
print 'LatLon:  ', datalatlon
```

The lat/lons appear in the source view but not in the actual web page. This should work so what am I missing ? If you examine the element the lat/lon is held as an html-attribute-value, but if you copy the xpath directly you get a different path as shown

```
#datalatlon = tree.xpath('//span[@class="/html/body/table/tbody/tr[229]/td[2]/span[1]/span[2]"]/text()')
```

Neither work however. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all:  Why are you trying to scrape an open-source project?!
You can just [download the data](https://alpha.openaddressesuk.org/data), and process how you wish.

And if you have to query results one by one, use the json API, which requires a lot less resources to process. in your case:

https://alpha.openaddressesuk.org/streets/frm7qQ.json